# TypeScript/JavaScript: Calling a function from a custom contextmenu item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a ContextMenuItem model defined as:

```
export class ContextMenuItem {
    label: string;
    action?: () => void;
}
```

In my class I am defining a list of them as:

```
contextMenuItems: ContextMenuItem[] = [{
    label: 'Open link in new tab',
    action: () => this.openLinkInNewTab()
},
{
    label: 'Test 2',
    action: () => this.testFunc()
}];
```

HTML for my custom context menu:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="test1">
        <div (pointerdown)="mouseDown($event)" class="test">Test Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hide" id="menu">
        <ul class="menu-items">
            <li *ngFor="let menuItem of contextMenuItems">
                <div (click)="menuItem.action()">{{ menuItem.label }}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code being called when the Test Text is right clicked:

```
mouseDown(mouseClick: PointerEvent) {
    let rightClick: number = 3;
    if (mouseClick.which !== rightClick) return;

    if (document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let element = document.getElementById('menu');
            element.classList.toggle('hide');

            element.style.position = 'absolute';
            element.style.zIndex = '1';
            element.style.top = event.layerY + 'px';
            element.style.left = event.layerX + 'px';
        }, false);
    }

    document.addEventListener('pointerdown', function (event) {
        document.getElementById('menu').classList.add('hide');
    });
}
```

Now, whenever I try to click on any of my ContextMenuItems, the function doesn't get hit at all. I've tried doing a console.log at the beginning of the function and it never displays. I also tried setting a breakpoint. There's also nothing in the network tab on the debugger tools when an item is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. In a StackBlitz it works fine... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ephmha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Register the listener before you wait for the user click e.g. Use OnInit() to subscribe the context menu clicks and try again.

Note: better to use Angular data binding than using .add class native DOM method as its not supported in old IEs